# Managing conflict of events in parent-child div

Tags: javascript, html

Look at the following code:

```
<div onmousedown="alert('onmousedown');">
    <div onclick="alert('onclick');"></div>
</div>
```

My question is, you can disable the onmousedown event while is active the onclick event of the div child?

Comment: With this structure, I don't think there's any way not to have a conflict.  You will have to remove mouse click events from the parent if you want them to be observed in the child.

Comment: The problem is that there are also other elements, which must follow the rules of the parent...

Comment: @user2799274 `mousedown` is triggered before `click`, and they are not active at the same time

Comment: Yes i know, I would like to activate the onclick and not onmousedown if I click on the div child...

Answer (score 0):

If you use `mousedown` and `mouseup` instead of `click` on the child div, then you can try an algorithm something like this:

```
var flag;

onchildmousedown() {
    flag = true;
}

onchildmouseup() {
    flag = false;
    // other click processing on child
}

onparentmousedown() {
    if (flag) {
        flag = false;
        return;
    }
    // continue for processing
}
```

I am not sure if this works as I haven't tested it. But, you get the idea and can tweak it accordingly.